# lua variable name from user input

Tags: lua

I am trying to make a "shell" in lua.

But the main problem is, I can not define the variable name from user input.
Here is the core of what I currently have. I am having an issue with the `what[2] = what[3]` line with the comment below.

How can I better implement this?

```
function lsplit(inputstr, sep)
    if sep == nil then
        sep = "%s"
    end

    local t={} ; i=1
    for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep.."]+)") do
        t[i] = str
        i = i + 1
    end
    return t
end

function def(what)
    if (what[1] == "end") then
        os.exit(0)
    elseif (what[1] == "help") then
        print("Commander version 0.0")
    elseif (what[1] == "var") then
        what[2] = what[3] --Can not define
    else
        print("[ERR] not a command!")
    end
end

while(true) do
    io.write("-->")
    local usr = io.read("*l")
    local cmd = lsplit(usr, " ")
    def(cmd)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are overwriting you first parameter with you second one, and not creating a new var... try this code! Should work but it is untested!

```
local userdefinedVars = { }

function lsplit(inputstr)
    words = {}
    for word in s:gmatch("%w+") do
        table.insert(words, word)
    end
end

function def(what)
    if (what[1] == "end") then
        os.exit(0)
    elseif (what[1] == "help") then
        print("Commander version 0.0")
    elseif (what[1] == "var") then
        -- This is how you get your things done!
        userdefinedVars[what[2]] = what[3]
    else
        print("[ERR] not a command!")
    end
end

while(true) do
    io.write("--> ")
    local usr = io.read("*line")
    local cmd = lsplit(usr)
    def(cmd)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the idea really helps.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why he has downvoted? I can't improve my answer if you don't tell me what's wrong with it!

Comment: I am sorry, I have a error with my computer, the cursor is wrong with my mouse, I will change it back. Sorry.